# Java script unable to identify all variables

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement

Hi I'm getting started with JS and still some of the things happening here are a little enigmatic to me. My question is why third variable in my code **resultMarcin** is not being considered in my simple line of code?

```
var ageMike = 25;
var ageTom = 30;
var ageMarcin = 90;

var heightMike = 178 * 5;
var heightTom = 150 * 5;
var heightMarcin = 210 * 5;

var resultMike = ageMike + heightMike;
var resultTom = ageTom + heightTom;
var resultMarcin = ageMarcin + heightMarcin;


if (resultMike > resultTom && resultMarcin) {

    alert('Mike wins with score ' + resultMike);

} else if (resultTom > resultMike && resultMarcin) { 

    alert('Tom wins with score' + resultTom);

} else if (resultMarcin > resultMike && resultTom) {

    alert('Marcin wins with score' + resultMarcin);

} else if (resultMike === resultTom && resultMarcin) {

    alert("It's a tie");

}
```

Comment: What do you mean "not being considered"? What is the error you get?

Comment: You are only checking if resultMarcin is `true` or `false`

Comment: i think you want to do `if(resultMike > resultTom && resultMike > resultMarcin){/*your alert*/}`, as it is now it checks if resultMike is larger than resultTom and if resultMarcin is a truthy value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is if statement.

```
if (resultMike > resultTom && resultMarcin) {
```

should be

```
if (resultMike > resultTom && resultMike > resultMarcin) {
```

because `resultMarcin` is `truthy` in JavaScript. If value is >0 it will just give you `true`, so your if statement says:

```
 if (resultMike > resultTom && true)
```

which means, second part of if is always true, so in fact it checks only first mive vs tom.

Here is some more information about it: 
https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/